# Debugger Visualizer for non-managed C++ code?

Tags: c++, debugging, unmanaged, visualizer

Does anyone know of a C++ IDE or debugger that's supports debugger visualizers for unmanaged C++ code? The problem is that Visual Studio's debugger visaulizer supports only managed C++.

Thanks,

- Olumide

PS: I'm still open to using VS if I can find a technique for making the visualizer work with unmanaged C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the [custom visualizers](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=120) in Visual Studio 2005+ (basically editing autoexp.dat) what you need?

Comment: Thanks guys. I will look into the options you suggested. 

If it matters, I'm writing a graphics program and I'm looking to find a way to make the debugger write any selected objects to the filesystem while debugging. See for example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/GraphicDebuggerVisualizer.aspx

Thanks.

Comment: For that you need to write an AddIn DLL like the one described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fwk67y3%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) debugger for unmanaged code. AFAIK, it only works on *nix systems.